# Enviar datos de log desde un boton php

Tags: php

Quiero que mediante un botón que tengo en php de esta forma:

```
echo CHtml::button(Yii::t('site', 'Help (F2)'), array('id' => 'run_example'));
```

y este ejecuta una funcion asi

```
<script>
//funcion para el intro
$("#run_example").click(function(){
Sideshow.start({ listAll: true });
});
</script>
```

Lo que necesito hacer, es que cuando el usario haga clic en ese botón se envíe  el nombre de usuario, la fecha y hora a una tabla en la base de datos

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: que framework estas utilizando? Ese tipo de cosas se suelen hacer mediante eventos, de manera que cuando se ejecute el php de ese boton, algun servicio capture dicha accion y pueda hacer algo a mayores...

Comment: Estoy usando ajax

Comment: La instrucción de `echo CHtml...` es javascript???

Comment: Es un boton en PHP

Comment: vale, estas usando Yii Framework. (lo que te preguntaba al principio). En el manual de la web https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml#chtmlbutton-method hay una opcion (example 3) para mandar parametros a tu controlador, y ahi es donde harias la insercion en bbdd. Revisa eso